# Is is possible to send cookie from http://localhost

Tags: cookies, localhost, httponly

I'm using Chrome, my FE is running on http://localhost:3000, and my BE server is running on http://localhost:8000.

I just want to store my refreshToken to cookie, using **httpOnly: true**, and I do it in BE. Of course I configured my request with **withCredentials: true** too.

I found that cookie only can be sent from different origin if **secure: true**, **sameSite: None**, but localhost is insecure

I went so far to realize that it does not work with **http**, whose default protocol of localhost. Is there any way to use cookies without using TLS in localhost?

Please correct me if I miss something important, I'm just a noob at this. Tks!